# Как сделать отступы между view в scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

Добавляю в `LinearLayout` `View` элементы программно

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        View post = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post, null);
        postsView.addView(post);

        TextView postUserName = (TextView) post.findViewById(R.id.postUserName);
        postUserName.setText("Me");
    }
```

Родительский `View` это `ConstraintLayout`.Задал параметры

```
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```

Но отступы все равно не наблюдаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать разрывы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно установить отступы для разметки добавляемых элементов, а не для их контейнера. Это можно как в разметке сделать (в вашем случае - в `post.xml`) или программно (после добавления в контейнер) как-то так:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) post.getLayoutParams();
params.bottomMargin = 50;
params.topMargin = 50;
```

---

И да - вам надо не добавлять программно создаваемые вьюхи в `ScrollView`, а использовать `RecyclerView` - он специально предназначен для отображения наборов данных и включает в себя множество оптимизаций для такого рода задач.

Comment: Как это сделать в разметке?

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, точно также, как вы пробовали для контейнера. Надо добавить `android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"` для корневого элемента разметки в файле `post.xml`

Comment: добавил. бесполезно. сейчас обновлю

Comment: обновил вопрос .

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, разметку надо текстом, не картинкой. По сути - странно, должно работать. Может у вас `InstantRun` не отключён и сбоит? Попробуйте его отключить. Также можно попробовать заменить `margin` на `padding`.

Comment: заработало. все. спасибо большое

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, пожалуйста)

Comment: кстати. не подскажите. как на каждую вьюшку повесить или тэг или id, что потом отлавливать нажатия и по нажатия загружать еще данные по этому тэгу или id

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, тут в двух словах не объяснить. Если делать правильно - у вас должна быть модель данных, содержащая этот самый ID. У вас должен быть список/массив этих данных. Каждая ваша `вьюха-post` должна отображать эти данные из списка. И делать это обязательно надо через `RecyclerView`. В принципе, любой урок по этому виджету должен показывать как это сделать.

Comment: реализовал. в цикле(который в вопросе) вешаю на каждый пост ID(i), а потом в onClick() достаю его.

Comment: еще вопросик))) как post добавить еще view. addView() не робит. допустим если в нем есть фото то нужно ImageView запихнуть.

Comment: Да, это будет работать, но это концептуально неверное решение и годится только для демонстрации. Как правильно - я описал выше. Также, не стоит в комментариях это обсуждать. Лучше будет, если новые вопросы будут задаваться отдельными вопросами)

Comment: ок. сейчас напишу